# how to check the missing dependencies in golang

Tags: go

How can I know what are the missing dependencies in a go project?
Now the only way I know is to run the `go build` command and follow the error messages.

But is there any more efficient way to do that such as:

`./a.out proj`

and the return maybe like:

`missing dependencies:
github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql
github.com/foo/bar
....`

Does `go build` support this function?

Answer (score 1):

Since Go is compiled language so in order to see if your code has an error or missing dependencies is by compiling your code. 
You can use `go get` as an alternative of `go build` to see your missing dependencies.

some reference from [doc](https://golang.org/doc/)

> Go compiles quickly to machine code yet has the convenience of garbage
>   collection and the power of run-time reflection. It's a fast,
>   statically typed, compiled language that feels like a dynamically
>   typed, interpreted language.

Comment: What will u do if u are asked to develop a software which is used to complie other's project?Maybe what u received is only a `main.go`,what should u do next?Analyze this source code yourself and fetch the dependencies remotely one by one?I just want to know if there's a simple way to get the missing dependencies or I need to do it my own

Comment: @caibirdme if you like the job patience and hard work is the key, otherwise quit as soon as possible.